# Implementing a list box in WPF that looks like the "Songs" view in Windows Media Player 11?

Tags: wpf, listview

I'd like to implement a view in my WPF application that looks like the Windows Media Player 11 Songs view.

That is: Broken into categories by album. Each album has a the album art and album details. On the right is the list of tracks on that album, with further details.

Any pointers? I'm fairly new to WPF.

Note: Windows Media Player 11 just uses a normal SysListView32 control, which is presumably subclassed to hell and back.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips to get you started:

- Your view models should include collections of type `ObservableCollection<T>` to allow the UI to detect and automatically reflect any changes made.
- Your views should use `CollectionViewSource`s to group and sort the data.
- Read up on implementing [master-detail](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?m=200511) in WPF.